# Chrome/Safari sets width of inline element before content loads

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit

Chrome and Safari seem to set the width of the following  element before the content loads so in effect it has no width.  But in firefox it sets the width to the width of the loaded text correctly. It needs to be inline and with no width so that the background is set to the width of the dynamic content. Any solutions?

```
<a class="text></a>
```

CSS:

.text {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 1px solid rgb(217, 195, 169);
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var data;
    function loadContent(){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: "json/content.json",
            data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(source){
                data = source;
                showInfo();
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("Failed to load content");
            }
        }); 

    }

    loadContent();
        function showInfo(){
            $(".text").html(data[lang]['startpage']['text']);
    }
   showInfo();
    });
```

Comment: What does the `<a>` contain after `$(".text").html(data[lang]['startpage']['text']);`?

Comment: just test eg. "contact"

Comment: I don't see how this could have anything to do with the ajax loading of the link text. I would rather guess there are some other style rules applying to `a` or `.text`, that for some reason behave differently in different browsers. Do you get other results if you have the link text there initially and don't set it using ajax?

Comment: no it only happens when setting with ajax for some reason, any ideas?

Comment: Not really... Do you get the same results on http://jsfiddle.net/ZZvce/1/ ?

Comment: that works ok for me :S does that mean something is wrong in the css? I'll post all the css

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the CSS. Actually I've never experience that CSS would affect dynamic content differently than static content. My final longshot guess is that some javascript somehow fixes the width of the `<a>` before the contents are added.

Comment: you can see the problem here: http://alexanderlloyd.info/test/